# Which lumber size to use for towel rod mount?

Tags: wood, mounting

I am a complete novice for any DIY work, but I wanted to hang up a towel rod on a 30" strip of drywall ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08T7F8V8R)). There is a stud in the middle, and at each end, so I thought to install a plank to catch the studs at the end, and then mount the towel rod on the plank.

Considering that, and that the bases of the rods I was considering seem to be a bit over 2 inches, should I use a 2'x4' plank, or would some other plank dimensions be more appropriate?

Comment: Can you clarify? You say there's a stud in the middle, and at each end...why the plank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For decades those type of towel bars have been mounted into drywall.

To do so the bars usually come with plastic anchors that go into the drywall and then screws are fastened through plates into the plastic anchors to hold the plates to the wall.   Then the bar ends are attached to the plates fastened to the wall.

The weak points of this process are the plastic anchors and the cheep screws.
For that reason before you try to mount the bar, purchase better plastic anchors and screws. [Drywall anchors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09H38ZYDD) or these [Winged anchors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P6ZBNHQ) Each type come in various sizes. Some are rated to hold 100lbs or more. ( plenty for holding towels)

Installed correctly these make a secure towel bar. However it is a **towel bar**  not a grab bar to hoist yourself up.

Answer (score 4):

A 1x4 or 1x5 will probably be enough if screwing it into studs.

Depending on what you like, but maybe stain it with some brass screws to hold it or paint to match the wall.

A 1x will be about 3/4 inch thick, much nicer looking than an inch and a half lump on the the wall.  Could also use 3/4 plywood, but unless you have a small piece you kept for the last forty years, a 1x will be cheaper.

A support bar for people should be directly screwed into studs